# How to dynamically import a component in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to import a component onto a page and the component uses a package that uses the window property. So, I need to dynamically import the component.

How can I do the following with Gatsby? (This is in NextJS)

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
...
const MyComponent = dynamic(() =>
    import('path').then((comp) => comp.default),
  );
```

Comment: Decided to move everything over the Next for several reasons including the dynamic importing

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your `js script` to your component. `window` property is not native.
Check it, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553060/nextjs-script-tag-not-loading-amplitude/71558289#71558289)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this solves it. Window is used by a package dependency (powerbi-client) and I need to dynamically import a component I built (that relies on that package).