# AddThis script only loads once in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, addthis

I want to add AddThis social buttons to my articles.

In NextJS, the AddThis script only loads once when the site has been loaded.
If I go to other articles/pages then this AddThis social buttons wont appear.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

I've tried NextJS <Script> component, useEffect, useRouter, but it won't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because `<Script>` tag will run only once per page load. While you are clicking, for example, `<Link>` tag, the page is not really reloaded.

Check what you can do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558289/8280112), if you have dynamic scripts you need "force add" them to you page with useEffect.